# Rails | installing country_select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems

I'm having trouble setting up a gem in my rails app. I'm doing the following:

```
gem 'country_select', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/country_select.git'
```

Trying to make use of the gem found here:

```
https://github.com/rails/country_select
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find gem 'country_select (>= 0, runtime)' in git://github.com/rails/country_select.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'country_select (>= 0, runtime)'
```

Comment: Try using the 'carmen' gem > https://github.com/jim/carmen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not installing as a gem because it's not a gem, it's a plugin.

Below are the install direction for Rails

**Rails3**

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/rails/country_select.git
```

**Rails2**

```
ruby script/plugin install https://github.com/rails/country_select.git
```

Comment: Rails 4 will no longer support plugins, it's better to use the gem now.

Answer (score 30):

I just [forked and gemified](https://rubygems.org/gems/country-select) this plugin, if it is of any use to you.

```
# Gemfile
gem "country-select"
```

Comment: Nice! An answer plus a resource.

Comment: As of this comment date, the gem is being regularly updated. Use it rather than the plugin.